# Calculating required bytes to store an integer

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu-architecture, ram

Given that our RAM unit has 6 address bits going into it and a 32-bit architecture, how many bytes would be needed to store one integer value? The answer says 4 bytes, but I don't understand why that is the case.

Could someone please help me understand how they got 4?

Comment: On a 32-bit architecture, you'd normally choose the width of an `int` to be 32-bit, same width as a register, which is 4 bytes, regardless of how many total bytes of RAM there are (and thus how many address bits you have).  You can't "calculate" this, it's an arbitrary choice.  You can also have 1-byte integer values, like C `int8_t`, that you use to save space for things that don't need a big value-range.

Comment: At heart it's a very badly asked question. "32-bit architecture" is not a precise term. _If_ you assume 32 bits is the data path/register width _and also_ assume that an integer is represented by that width, _and also_ assume that a byte has 8 bits, _then_ you get 32/8=4 bytes.  E.g. plenty of 8086-era systems implemented 32- and 64-bit integers even though they were 16-bit architectures. Not to mention 8-bit (as Peter mentioned) and BCD integers .

Comment: Of course, on a 64-bit ISA most C implementations still chose 32-bit `int` because that's wide enough, and C with 32-bit `int` had been in widespread use for long enough that much code existed which worked better with that (or *only* with that).  So it's not a rule that the default integer data type in whatever language has to be the same width as a register.  For example, in x86-64 machine code, the default operand-size is 32-bit.  So unless you were given more info about how wide that integer was that implied register-width, this is a very poor assignment question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of address bits doesn't really factor in to the basic of storing an integer.  (More on that later.)

You need to know:

1. how many bits an integer takes
2. how many bits are stored per memory location/address

Given those you can compute the number of memory locations needed to hold an int of that size, i.e.

32 bits per integer / 8 bits per memory location = 4 memory locations per integer.

If the machine stores 8 bits per memory address, then it is what we call [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing), and it will necessarily take multiple bytes to store anything larger than 8 bits.  Using multiple bytes also means using multiple addresses: the most common convention is that the entire multi-byte object is referred to by the (numerically) lowest address it uses.  Because a multi-byte entity takes multiple addresses, the next available address for some other purpose needs to be beyond the final byte of the multi-byte item.

Some machines are word addressable, meaning that a single memory address stores more than 8 bits, sometimes 16, or 18, or larger.

It is useful to have an integer size that can store a pointer, but in your case, a pointer only needs 6 bits, whereas on most 32-bit machines a pointer needs 32 bits.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes; removed references to the C data type..